# Using RVM with different gemsets in TextMate

Tags: ruby, textmate, rvm

I have set up RVM and made individual gemsets for my projects as per the [RVM best practices](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/best-practices). Now running a test file in TextMate dosen't work and I have [read here](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/textmate) what to do. The problem is that it won't work because the guide expects me to have just one gemset (they call it "Rails3"). I normally have 2-3 projects open at a time (using different gemsets) so I can't effectively use this approach.

Have any of you solved that problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found the RVM wrappers method to be very buggy, and as you've discovered it doesn't work at all with gemsets unless you do a lot of tedious setup.

I've had some success using the following script as `TM_RUBY`:

```
#!/bin/bash

base_dir=${TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY:-$PWD}
cd $base_dir
exec $MY_RUBY_HOME/bin/ruby $*
```

As long as you're in a TextMate project and you have a `.rvmrc` file in the project root it will run your code in the Ruby version and gemset specified in the `.rvmrc`. The `cd` makes sure RVM discovers the `.rvmrc`.

Put the code above into `~/bin/textmate_ruby_wrapper` and then go to Preferences > Advanced > Shell Variables and set `TM_RUBY` to that same path.

Comment: Man, I've been [saving my upvotes for questions](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/155/electorate), but I gotta spend one on this. Very nice!

Comment: So close!  I've tried this solution but get the message:

Can't find “~/bin/textmate_ruby_wrapper” on PATH.

Comment: I found adding the line `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` after the shebang made this solution more robust.

Comment: Wow I've been trying to track down a solution and this is one of the few I was comfortable with

Answer (score 0):

I've found this solution which is even simpler.  Under the TextMate Preferences - Advanced - Shell Variables:

Set your **GEM_HOME**:

```
env | grep GEM_HOME | awk '{ sub(/GEM_HOME=/, ""); print }'
```

Set your **GEM_PATH**:

```
env | grep GEM_PATH | awk '{ sub(/GEM_PATH=/, ""); print }'
```