# Textmate does not run ruby with the latest version

Tags: ruby, textmate

I have updated my ruby to 1.9.3.

However, when I run my ruby code in Textmate, it still run with 1.8.7 version.

To be more specific, here is my test code, just one line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -v
```

when running in Textmate (command + R), the result is:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

when running in the command line (./test.rb), the result is:

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.0.0]
```

so how to edit my Textmate to support the newest ruby?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using RVM with different gemsets in TextMate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948915/using-rvm-with-different-gemsets-in-textmate)

Answer (score 3):

Try to edit the TM_RUBY shell variable to point to your newly installed version. According to the docs, it should be somewhere under /usr/local (most likely /usr/local/bin/ruby).

You can find out the location of your ruby installation by typing the following in your terminal window:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

then perform the following to verify the version

```
$ ruby -v
```

Once you have the proper ruby path, in Textmate, double-click the 'value' of the TM_RUBY shell variable & type in the path to your 1.9.3 install.

Comment: 'double-click the 'value' of the TM_RUBY shell variable', where is it?

Comment: In menu TextMate > Preferences... > Variables

Comment: @Noé. I followed your words, and something strange happen: when I have #!/usr/bin/env ruby in the first line, the textmate will run ruby 1.8.7, otherwise it will run the latest version.